# Pony ORM and IAM based connection to AWS PostgreSQL RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, ponyorm

I am building a service using Python, Pony ORM and PostgreSQL. I plan hosting it in AWS. I will use AWS RDS PostgreSQL.

AWS supports passwordless connection to RDS (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-connect-using-iam/, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html).

Essentially, I have to generate a short-living password before connecting to my database:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='RDSCreds')
client = session.client('rds')
token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USER, Region=REGION)
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=ENDPOINT, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, user=USER, password=token, sslrootcert="SSLCERTIFICATE")
```

Is there a way to integrate this approach with Pony ORM? Under the hood Pony just delegates connection to `psycopg2`. `psycopg2` accepts username and password. But how can I make sure that when Pony reconnects to the database, there's a token that it can use?